# table width, how is it calculated?

Tags: jquery, html, css, html-table

I working on a locked headers jquery plugin and i am running into a problem where a table width is smaller than the sum of the column widths.

Here is how locked header plugins work: You create another table containing your table's original header and put it into a table thats floated above the original table. You then make sure the floated table's column widths and the original table's column widths are equal.

I am running into a problem where if a table has a width of 100% **and** its inside of a container with overflow, it seems that the table's width is not controlled by the sum of its column widths.

if the table is not in a container, it works.

see this test case:
http://programmingdrunk.com/floatThead/examples/big-table.htm

the first table should be as wide as the floated header. you can see that the column widths do not match up.

the 2nd table works fine because its not within a container with overflow:auto;

Comment: one solution would be to explicitly set the table width of the table to the sum of the column widths. this works but there are other repercussions caused by changing a percent width to a pixel width that i would like to avoid

Answer (score 0):

You're using table-layout: fixed. Just reading up on it, it seems that with this, the first row of a table is used in calculating the width of a table. Your first row appears to be empty when I inspect it, maybe that's causing the issue?

Without any content, this width would be equal to 100% of the container, based on your css, which seems to be what's happening.

Try changing to `table-layout: auto`, although I suspect you may be relying on the current style.

Comment: i use a `<colgroup>` with `<col>` tags as my first row. This drives the widths of each column. if you are using chrome inspector you wont be able to see the widths of the cols because of a chrome bug. use firebug ;)

Comment: Hmm, nothings jumping out at me. Hope you figure it out.